# Mysqldb problems copying django site to new server

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm stuck.  I'm trying to replicate my fedora setup on a second server.  I've got problems.  My environment:
- mysql (mariadb)
- python3
- django
- apache with mod_wsgi

I'm getting a 500 Internal server error.  When I zoom in on the httpd error_log I see this:

```
    [Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.119939 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304] mod_wsgi (pid=2728): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/at/at/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120097 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120178 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]   File "/var/www/html/at/at/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120190 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120206 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120214 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120228 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120236 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120250 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]   File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120258 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Mon Apr 09 22:44:14.120285 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 2728:tid 140190313469696] [client 192.168.1.123:52304] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

and when I attempt to run python3 manage.py I get the following errors -- it looks to me like its having trouble talking with the database?  I have already created the database in mysql and uploaded the contents from a mysqldump.  so I don't get the problem.   I also have installed mysql-python which I think is what gets me python3-mysql connectivity.

Here's how it complains when I try python3 manage.py:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Any clues you guys can offer me would help.  I'm finding it very difficult to reproduce my production server.  (kind of regretting doing the django thing).

Best
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom I assume you had the same set up running locally correct?

Comment: You need to install MySQLdb, but it only supports python 2.x.

Comment: Hey guys -- yes I have the system running on a production server.  To get the connector between django and python3.x I used Ian Clelland's mysql-to-python connector -- https://github.com/clelland/MySQL-for-Python-3.  However magic is not there.   -- Alternatively I'd be open to strait up cloning my server drive but unfortunately is LVM over like 3 different MMCblk devices so I don't see an easy way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

for others who may be having this problem let me explain what I found:

My site is written PRE DJANGO 2.0 and after LOTS and LOTS of searching I finally came upon the answer.   The problem was not with the installed connector or packages -- they were all fine.   The problem is that in Django 2.0 FOREIGN FUNCTIONS NOW MUST SPECIFY AN on_delete ACTION!!!  So you need something that looks like this:

in your models.py (check every one of them for ForeignKey).  Must be in the form:

```
heading = models.ForeignKey(ForumSections, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

there are other options but if you don't have the on_delete part starting in 2.0 you will see the errors I was struggling with.

Good luck to you all.

Cheers,
Tommy